# Why is this PHP-MySQL code not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

It was working before and maybe someone made changes to the code and I cant detect the problem after much debugging so hopefully someone can help.

I have an html form that lets a user choose a set of option and then on form submit, POSTS these options in an array which works perfectly fine. Then I am writing the elements of an array to a MySQL table and this is where the problem occurs. My code was working fine before but now its all weird. The outputs mix up for some reason.

Below is the array values passed and then the output below the arrays.

[image]

Here is my code that writes the array values to MySQL:

```
error_reporting(-1);
$arr=$_POST["itemsToAdd"];

$cal=$_POST["calendar"];

print_r($arr);

// Make a MySQL Connection


//empty table first to remove any previous old on-calls stored.
$query = "truncate table ProdOnCallSetup";
if(mysql_query($query)){
}
else{
}




foreach ($arr as &$value) {

// Insert a row of information into the table "ProdOnCallSetup"
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ProdOnCallSetup
(Email) VALUES('$value') ") 
or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Here is the code giving the output or displaying the rows in MySQL:

```
<ol class=”list_style”>

    <?php
//make MySQL connection

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ProdOnCallSetup";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<li>".$row['Email']."</li>";
        echo "<br />";
    }


    ?>

</ol>
```

See the problem here? Even though I write them in the correct order in MySQL when I display them the order mixes up. Order is Justin, Achau, Chellatamby but when I echo is out from the DB its Achau, Chellatamby, Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically use an ORDER BY clause in your SELECT statement, the order in which rows are returned is **indeterminate** and may change.... it doesn't matter what order you added the records in, this is irrelevant...  use ORDER BY...

```
SELECT * FROM ProdOnCallSetup ORDER BY Email
```

(or whatever column id you want to order them on)

If you want to order them in the order you added them to the database, you'll need an autoincrement column on the table, and order by that column

Comment: I tried order by email and it didnt do anything, still the same order, I am autoincrementing the email column on the table so how would I return it from DB using that?

EDIT: I see what you mean it orders them based on their alphabetetical email name but I have autoincrement as well how would I return the column in the order I added them to DB>?

Comment: Use ORDER BY pid in your SELECT statement (where pid is the name you've given to your autoincrement column).... it isn't your Email column, because that's the column with the email address in... then read a few tutorials on how to use MySQL, because this is absolute basics

Comment: How can I retrieve the id of my MySQL table to see if I have an id set, I remember a while back auto_increment didnt support all variable types..

Comment: I am not 100% sure why this isnt working for me but perhaps Ill try recreating my table and see if I can fix this with the id.

Comment: You a directional indicator. SELECT * FROM ProdOnCallSetup ORDER BY Email ASC;

Comment: Autoincrement columns should be a pid number, so something like an INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, and a primary key